# SignalR: The remote server returned an error: (500) Inter nal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I have installed both client and server of signalR in my MVC project; and I am able to call my hub from the web client;

```
var testHub;
$(function () {
    // Setup SignalR
    testHub = $.connection.myhub;
    testHub.msg = function (ref) {
        alert(ref);
    };

    $.connection.hub.start(function () {
        testHub.addToQueue("TESTMSG");
    });

});
```

And on a controller, I need to call my hub after processing some request; so I have added references to SignalR.Client.dll -Version(0.5.2.0) and Newtonsoft.Json.dll(4.5.0.0) runtime 4.

My controller call is as below

```
  var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:50439/");
        IHubProxy myHub = connection.CreateProxy("myhub");
        connection.Start().Wait();
        myHub.Invoke("addToQueue", new { message = "Hello world" }).ContinueWith(task =>
        {


        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

And my hub looks as below:

```
 [HubName("myhub")]
public class QueueHub:Hub
{
    public void addToQueue(string message)
    {
        Clients.msg(message);
    }
}
```

But when the call from controller happens, the system gets below error:
Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 46., JsonSerializer

And In details:

```
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred
. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Inter
nal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at SignalR.Client.Http.HttpHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<GetHttpResponseAsync>b_
_0(IAsyncResult ar) in C:\Documents and Settings\mrafeeq\My Documents\Downloads\
SignalR-SignalR-0.5.0-231-g7808c90\SignalR-SignalR-7808c90\SignalR.Client\Http\H
ttpHelper.cs:line 19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the server side method incorrectly. You need to do this:

```
myHub.Invoke("addToQueue", "Hello world").ContinueWith(task =>
{


}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Comment: Thanks David, So simple call. Its fixed my issue :-)